# Error while installing an app from Windows 8 store

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-apps

I get this error when installing applications like Facebook, Skype etc. from Windows 8 store -- "Your purchase couldn't be completed error :0*80070422". 
Firewall has been turned on as suggested by few forums but this error is still there. Had Windows 8 installed just 2 days back.

Comment: Try to run `%SystemRoot%\system32\WSReset.exe` as admin.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means you have disabled a required service:

```
C:\Users\André>err 0x80070422
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_WIN32 (0x7), Code 0x422
# for hex 0x422 / decimal 1058
  ERROR_SERVICE_DISABLED                                         winerror.h
# The service cannot be started, either because it is
# disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated
# with it.
# 1 matches found for "0x80070422"
```

Open the services MMC snapin and make sure that the Store Service (`WSService`) is running. Also look into the eventlog and `"C:\Windows\Temp\winstore.log"` for more details which service is not running.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing required.
Go to services.msc
 and start Windows Update service.
 Try again.

If this fixes your issue, let me know.